# opencv do_compile bitbake error because of undefined opencl sample code header

Tags: c++, opencv, yocto, bitbake

I add my `bblayer.conf` with meta-openembedded layer in order to install opencv library on my 64-bit image.
But on 99% `do_compile()` phase, it gave me error which it seems opencl header (CL/cl.h) on `opencl_opencl-opencv-interop.cpp`

```
   | FAILED: bin/example_opencl_opencl-opencv-interop
   | : && /home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-clang++  --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ -mlittle-endian -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument -Qunused-arguments -I/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/git/include   --sysroot=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0=/usr/src/debug/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  --stdlib=libc++ --stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ -mlittle-endian -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument -Qunused-arguments -I/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/git/include   --sysroot=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Winconsistent-missing-override -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -Qunused-arguments -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG  --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ -mlittle-endian -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument -Qunused-arguments -I/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/git/include   --sysroot=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0=/usr/src/debug/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  --stdlib=libc++ --stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ --rtlib=compiler-rt --stdlib=libc++ -mlittle-endian -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument -Qunused-arguments -I/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/git/include   --sysroot=/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed  -Wl,--gc-sections     -rdynamic samples/opencl/CMakeFiles/example_opencl_opencl-opencv-interop.dir/opencl-opencv-interop.cpp.o  -o bin/example_opencl_opencl-opencv-interop  -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt lib/libopencv_video.so.3.4.3 lib/libopencv_highgui.so.3.4.3 -lOpenCL lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.4.3 lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.4.3 lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4.3 lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.3 && :
   | /home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-ld: samples/opencl/CMakeFiles/example_opencl_opencl-opencv-interop.dir/opencl-opencv-interop.cpp.o: in function `~App':
   | /usr/src/debug/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/git/samples/opencl/opencl-opencv-interop.cpp:507: undefined reference to `clFinish'
   | /home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-ld: /usr/src/debug/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/git/samples/opencl/opencl-opencv-interop.cpp:508: undefined reference to `clReleaseCommandQueue'

   ...

   | /home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-ld: samples/opencl/CMakeFiles/example_opencl_opencl-opencv-interop.dir/opencl-opencv-interop.cpp.o:/usr/src/debug/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/git/samples/opencl/opencl-opencv-interop.cpp:265: more undefined references to `clGetDeviceInfo' follow
   | clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   | ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
   | WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
   | ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/temp/log.do_compile.17312)
```

Below is step to reproduce the error

1. Setting bitbake environment variable

   $ source meta/meta-myimages/oe-init-build-env
2. Add opencv 3.4.3 recipe to `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` variable

   IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " opencv "
3. Bitbake pointed image, let say `myimages`

   $ bitbake myimages

I used opencv 3.4.3 recipe.
If I disable opencl compilation by disabling it on CMakeList.txt, it gaves me another error like this

```
do_package: QA Issue: opencv: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib6464/libopencv_shape.so
  /usr/lib6464/libopencv_reg.so.3.4
  /usr/lib6464/libopencv_tracking.so.3.4.3
  /usr/lib6464/libopencv_bioinspired.so.3.4.3
  /usr/lib6464/libopencv_xphoto.so
...
```

I ever tried by overwriting `FILES_${PN}=""` variable with

```
FILES_${PN}="/usr/lib6464/* /usr/lib64/* "
```

However, it throws me `do_package_qa()` error

```
ERROR: opencv-3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_shape.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_xphoto.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_objdetect.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_plot.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_datasets.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_calib3d.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_ccalib.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_bioinspired.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_photo.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_imgcodecs.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_dpm.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_rgbd.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_img_hash.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_superres.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_highgui.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_line_descriptor.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_videoio.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_face.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_videostab.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_xobjdetect.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_features2d.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_tracking.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_video.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_ts.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_hfs.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_core.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_reg.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_structured_light.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_bgsegm.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_ml.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_ximgproc.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_xfeatures2d.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_aruco.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_flann.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_imgproc.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_stitching.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_surface_matching.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_saliency.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_stereo.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_fuzzy.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_optflow.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: opencv path '/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_phase_unwrapping.so' [dev-so]
ERROR: opencv-3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0 do_package_qa: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:do_package_qa(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/meta/poky/meta/classes/insane.bbclass', lineno: 1005, function: do_package_qa
     1001:    warn_checks, error_checks = parse_test_matrix("QARECIPETEST")
     1002:    package_qa_recipe(warn_checks, error_checks, pn, d)
     1003:
     1004:    if 'libdir' in d.getVar("ALL_QA").split():
 *** 1005:        package_qa_check_libdir(d)
     1006:
     1007:    qa_sane = d.getVar("QA_SANE")
     1008:    if not qa_sane:
     1009:        bb.fatal("QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.")
File: '/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/meta/poky/meta/classes/insane.bbclass', lineno: 242, function: package_qa_check_libdir
     0238:                    if libdir not in rel_path and libexecdir not in rel_path:
     0239:                        # make sure it's an actual ELF file
     0240:                        elf = oe.qa.ELFFile(full_path)
     0241:                        try:
 *** 0242:                            elf.open()
     0243:                            messages.append("%s: found library in wrong location: %s" % (package, rel_path))
     0244:                        except (oe.qa.NotELFFileError):
     0245:                            pass
     0246:
File: '/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/meta/poky/meta/lib/oe/qa.py', lineno: 49, function: open
     0045:    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
     0046:        self.data.close()
     0047:
     0048:    def open(self):
 *** 0049:        with open(self.name, "rb") as f:
     0050:            try:
     0051:                self.data = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
     0052:            except ValueError:
     0053:                # This means the file is empty
Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/packages-split/opencv/usr/lib6464/libopencv_ts.so'

ERROR: opencv-3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0 do_package_qa: Function failed: do_package_qa
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/naoya-ito/sy_i50/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/opencv/3.4.3+gitAUTOINC+b38c50b3d0_1f6d6f0626_bdb7bb85f3_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.6057
```

I believe this error happened not because of opencv_3.4.3 code base, but I already have a big suspicious on `./meta-mymeta/machine/myimage.conf` settings, which is like this

```
DEFAULTTUNE ?= "aarch64" 
require conf/multilib.conf
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib64" 
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib64 = "cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4"
```

Could somebody please help me to solve this bitbake issue?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you enable/disable the packageconfig of opencl in opencv? http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/opencv/opencv_3.4.5.bb?h=warrior#n97
You can do in an opencv_%.bbappend in your own meta layer.

Comment: Thanks, I try to disabled `samples/` to be installed and now its compiled smoothly. But I wonder why the CL/cl.h became undefined on my case.